# Flutter Emulator Error Connecting to Service Protocol

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

I am having an Issue with Flutter in Android studio, where whenever I run my flutter app, it will print this error; "Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:53305/9So9Wn564F4=/ws" , and it will "disconnect" from the app in the emulator.
The app will still run, but I can't use functions like Hot Reload.

I am on a Windows machine, and Flutter Doctor does not indicate any errors.
I have tried to read up on similar issues on github posts, but I have been unable to resolve the problem.

Do any of you guys have any ideas on how to solve this issue?

The problem does not occur when running on an actual device, only in the emulator.

Comment: Same! Which flutter version are you using? I'm using 1.5.4-hotfix.2.

Comment: flutter_barcode_scan caused the error for me. Does anybody know a working barcode-package?

Comment: I just did a cold boot and it worked.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, can it be related to the firewall i have on my Zorin OS(Ubuntu based)

Comment: Try wiping emulator data

Answer (score 37):

A quick restart of the phone worked for me

Comment: Ty, the restart also worked for me.

Comment: Restarting the phone, Uninstalling the app, Restarting the pc, Cleaning the build folder solved the issue!

Comment: This may happen if you enabled developer mode on your device but didn't reboot it before running your app on it.

Answer (score 20):

If you return to a previous version of android, (Android Pie), you will no longer have this problem, it is related only to the latest versions of android (Q, 29), in others you will no longer have the problem.

Comment: Happens for me exactly for Android Pie//

Comment: I was able to overcome it by using 30+ API

Answer (score 11):

### What exactly happened

Hey I went into the same problem too.
I cannot use a Emulator inside windows because my pc is a very low end pc.
So, I had to use my phone instead. It is a Samsung Galaxy J2 Pro (SM-J210F) with Android **6.0.1 (Android Marshmallow)**.
I used that phone to develop flutter apps regularly, but suddenly, I went to this problem.

Here's what happened when I tried to run "Flutter Attach" in VS-Code(v1.52.0).

#### command

flutter attach --machine -d 420054e7960eb400

#### exception

StateError: Bad state: Existing VM service clients prevent DDS from taking control.

```
#0      DartDevelopmentService.startDartDevelopmentService (package:flutter_tools/src/base/dds.dart:83:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      FlutterDevice.connect.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:249:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

### Fixing the issue (In Windows 10)

So, I ran these commands to fix the issue.

#### Fixing the Flutter SDK

> -**flutter clean -v**

> -**flutter channel stable** ** (Optional if these didn't fix the issue)

> -**flutter upgrade -v**

> -**flutter pub cache repair -v** (Disclaimer: It will download each and every version of all the packages. Be sure to have really fast internet or give at least an hour to this.)

#### Configure your Proxy/VPN

If you are using a Proxy or VPN to connect to the internet,
Make sure that application isn't resolving localhost via that.(DNS)

#### Kill ADB and Dart processes.

After that, kill adb and dart process on Windows.
(I don't know exactly how to kill these in Mac/Linux. Sorry About That)
Run these commands in the Command Prompt.

> **taskkill /f /im dart***
> **taskkill /f /im adb*** (You can run "**adb kill-server**" too)

#### Fixing the ADB in the Windows (*Optional).

Navigate to **%HOMEDRIVE%:\Users%USERNAME%.android**"
In my case, It is ( C:\Users\Isira Adithya.android )
Then delete **adbkey**.

#### Fixing the Android Debugging in the Android Device

Disconnect the device from the computer.
Go to **Settings** -> **Developer Options**,
Turn off USB Debugging and Turn it on again.
Revoke USB Debugging authorizations.
Restart the device.

#### Update Windows and Android System (If above didn't solve the problem)

#### Conclusion

I think these steps should fix your problem.
Also I am still 16 years old and I am not a very experienced developer.
If these didn't fix, use this to get more info. [Github Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47204)

Answer (score 9):

Uninstall app in Emulator fixed same issue for me

Answer (score 5):

For my case, I met the error when I used 3rd parties such as facebook_login, twitter_login incorrectly.

To check:

- comment the libs from pubspec.yaml, corresponding code as well.

To fix:

- update correctly config for the 3rd parties.

Hope this help.

Comment: can you please tell me how to fix it. because I am getting same error

Comment: @RutvikGumasana: try commenting all of 3rd parties libs such as facebook, twitter..., code is using them as well. clean, reinstall app again

Comment: but i need to use this facebook libs. then how can I get out of this error?

Comment: @RutvikGumasana u need to configure facebook plugin correctly. To day, I try to integrate again. It runs well.

Comment: When i ran the project in xcode i got a better error: Add a key named FacebookClientToken to your Info.plist, and add your client token as its value. Adding this resolved my issue

Answer (score 4):

In virtual device manager, try one of these options.

```
Wipe Data
Cold Boot Now
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by:

- turn off my phone.
- disconnect.
- turn on my phone.

By doing this, you will restart the VM Service.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30964621)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I don't know how you can solve it on *Windows* but for **Mac Os** users: Go to System Preferences -> Network -> Click on your Phone -> Uncheck "Disable unless needed"
[image: Uncheck Disable unless needed]

Thanks to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46698#issuecomment-565643127

Comment: This sadly isn't related to fixing this problem when it occurs when using the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Try

**flutter run --release**

I faced the same issue after upgrading flutter 1.13 but the above command helped.

Comment: Got this message while trying this solution 'Release mode is not supported for emulators.'

Answer (score 2):

**You can solve it by restarting your phone or emulator.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

If not all above them works for you.

1. Remove android studio, reinstall and open Android Studio
2. Go to "More Actions"
3. Go to "SDK Manager"
4. Click "Android SDK"
5. Click "SDK Tools"
6. Untick Android SDK Command-line Tools(latest) apply and let the program delete the files.
7. Go back tick Android SDK Command-line Tools(latest) and let the program download again.

It just worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just closed the simulator, and ran it again.

Answer (score 1):

Try

> **flutter doctor -v**

I had faced same issue. So I run **flutter doctor -v** command.

Then I found the error

> **✗ Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses.**

**flutter doctor --android-licenses** this command resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a simliar problem with ios with the error message `Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:......`. I solved it by removing the app from the simulator and ran a clean in xcode, then it could build successfully from vs code!

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue but the only thing which solved my problem is to uninstall the app on my physical phone and I again try to run. and truly its work.

Comment: Re-installing every single time is a **real pain**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Flutter 2.10` or higher it may be that you tried to emulate a `Windows desktop` app but you don't have `Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.0)` installed.

Apparently, it won't let you emulate anything until you install VS.
Run `flutter doctor` to find out.

Answer (score 1):

check if you have enough storage in your phone.

I had the same problem and that was the reason.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Turn on your Emulator. The Emulator would be switched off.

Answer (score 1):

to my case after upgrading `flutter_facebook_auth` `^3.5.0` to `^5.0.8` version i had to add `FacebookClientToken`

**iOS**

`Info.plist`

```
<key>FacebookClientToken</key>
<string>YOUR-TOKEN-HERE</string>
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#configure-your-project

**Android**

`/app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="YOUT TOKEN HERE"/>
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#configure-your-project

Answer (score 0):

It seems it can be different things. In my case, I removed a package I was using, barcode_scan.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I go to xcode -> window -> device & simulator, under Installed Apps I remove some apps and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was caused by flutter_facebook_login plugin causing issue i removed it and i could afford to remove facebook login option but in your case you can try different version of flutter_facebook_login or you can use different plugin for loggin in using facebook.

Comment: i just removed the facebook dependency and the app is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Open the project in android studio => Start your Emulator - OR - Connect your android device with Debug mode "on" => Run the Project on android studio => Run your project from VS code or from command line using `flutter run`

Answer (score 0):

When I deleted the emulator in AVD Manager and rebuilt it, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was caused by phone screen saver. Emulator screen was locked. After
I pressed on power icon, the screen opened. then I run it again and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem after add some code in android folder.

1.Add below code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

2.Add your Facebook app id in strings.xml

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">380000000000000</string>
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb380000000000000</string>
```

3.Add dependencies in pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1
```

Pub get and run.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error message. In my case, the problem was just a configuration that I changed in Runner.xcodeproj.

Open runner.xcodeproj in Xcode, go to the General tab -> App Icons and Lauch Images -> "Launch Screen File". I had changed it to Main and that cause the error, changing back to "LaunchScreen" option solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too, the problem was I was using a vpn in my PC, I turned the vpn off, and everything just worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Open AVD from Android Studio and clear data of emulator and re-run again.
it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use an external device to run the output and it fails to connect the debugging url.
The reason what I think is the connection between my device and PC was lost during synchronizing the data
So for that, I just revoke the debugging option from the developer options in the settings.
For an emulator that is created by android studio, I sue to clean the data/ wipe data/ or go to settings inside the emulator and go to storage then clear the cache data (if an app is preinstalled manually uninstall the flutter app then remove the cache).
Also, run fluter clean and flutter pub get in the terminal/cmd then flutter run to target the emulator or personal device.

Answer (score 0):

In my case :

1- lock the emulator from the the normal screen locking button.

2- unlock the emulator.

3- Press the run button in Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing for the IntelliJ IDEA solution, probably the same in Android Studio. Add a new rule to the 'Inbound Rules' and 'Outbound Rules' sections of the firewall, and grant access to the program located at IntellijIDEAPath\jbr\bin\jcef_helper.exe. Example path: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Version 2022.3.3\jbr\bin\jcef_helper.exe

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when running flutter app in vscode.
Here's my vscode launch configuration.

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Flutter",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "flutterMode": "debug",
      "args": [
        "--verbose"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And because i use proxy, i have some proxy settigns in environment.

```
export https_proxy=http://172.23.32.1:7890
export http_proxy=http://172.23.32.1:7890
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.0,127.0.1.1,127.0.1.1,local.home,::1
```

At the beginning i didn't know why i had this problem "Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = [http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/xxxx=/ws"](http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/xxxx=/ws%22)
I tried `netstat -altp | grep xxxx` I can see port is listened.

My Solution
`I restart vscode then it works.`