# Flutter app works on API level 30 or lower but fails on higher levels

Tags: flutter, runtime-error, nosuchmethoderror, android-api-levels

My Flutter app functions correctly on API level 30 or lower and on real devices with higher API levels. However, when I run it on an emulator with an API level above 30, it fails during installation with the error message: "Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:51427/xFHsz1qdYHY=/ the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly." I have tried uninstalling the app, wiping the emulator data, and cold rebooting the emulator, but the issue persists. Any insights on resolving this would be appreciated.

Tried reinstalling app, expected successful installation.
After running flutter run --verbose
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCGoL.png)

Comment: It looks like some kind of emulator or your Flutter installation problem, not app itself. Try to run from terminal (`flutter run`) in verbose mode  (add `--verbose` flag)   and show outptut.

Comment: check verbose result

Answer (score 0):

Add the following two lines to the `android/app/build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'  
implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you mention the `compilesdk`, `targetsdk`, `minsdk` version in the app-level `build.gradle` file.

make the `targetsdkversion` to 34(latest) .

please mention if it doesn't work. Also post some screenshots of `build.gradle` file.

Comment: compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34

Comment: give the compile sdkVersion to 34 also and rebuild apk.

Comment: i think try this solution also.
[try the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093247/flutter-emulator-error-connecting-to-service-protocol)

Comment: same issue,actually i am worried it will accept google play store or not, because there is showing Pre-launch report found issues in your app
if this issue acceptable in google play console then no problem